# jsTree - expand and highlight node I clicked on previous page

Tags: highlight, jstree, expand

I tried to use jsTree because of easy creating static HTML list into tree.
Do not ask me why, but I need to use as source HTML list structure with links.
I have left column on the web with some div panel and tree navigation using jsTREE.

What I need:

1) User expands some nodes and let me say on 3rd level of three there is item with link
2) User click on the link, it will redirects the user on new page with some content
3) On the left there is still jsTREE and I need to expand the tree and highlight the node, user clicked in previous step.
The best for me would be to compare URL and HREF of hyperlink in tree.
If webpage URL and hyperlink href attribute in tree is the same, this node should be highlighted and expanded, so user can see, where he currently is.

Any idea, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

just use jstree plugins to do so:

```
"plugins": ["types", "wholerow", "conditionalselect"]
```